# Toggling the brightness between two states on an android phone

Tags: android, display

I am looking for a preferably free android app (not a widget, but an app, and working on android 12) that when one executes it, toggles the brightness between two states (that is a minimum and a maximum brightness states defined by the user).

Comment: You could probably utilize an automation app like Tasker or MacroDroid for that – see the [automation tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) on our Android sister site. At least Tasker allows to put shortcuts to its actions on the home screen, so you had an icon to tap and toggle.

Comment: @Izzy thank you for your suggestion, I look at these automation tools.